# DATE_DIFF Casting date column as date?

Tags: sql, presto

If I have a simple date diff filter as below:

```
date_diff('year', date_column_a, date_column_b)
```

If I need to cast or convert the date columns to date prior to `date_diff()` can I do it in the function itself?

Thanks!

Comment: It is quite unclear what you are asking. Please provide sample data, expected results, and if possible a deeper explanation of what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly:

> If I need to cast or convert the date columns to date prior to date_diff() can I do it in the function itself?

Yes, you can. To cast your arguments inside the parentheses, you would simply write something like:

```
date_diff('year', cast(date_column_a as date), cast(date_column_b as date))
```

Answer (score 0):

Yea you can do smething like this:

```
date_diff('year', fn_convertToDate(date_column_a), fn_convertToDate(date_column_b))
```

wih fn_convertToDate converting its input to date type